# FCM DeadlineExceededError for sending push notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications in a rolled-out fashion in batches of 20 tokens as follows. There seem to be no quotas applicable for FCM, unable to understand this error.

However, recently I have been seeing unexpected `DeadlineExceededError`

```
            data={<2-3 key value pairs>},
            tokens=tokens,
            apns=messaging.APNSConfig(payload=messaging.APNSPayload(aps=messaging.Aps(content_available=True))),
        )
        return messaging.send_multicast(message)
```